# Parse url with json object

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json

i want to create json object with entityset

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "EntitySet": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "id": 1,
            "title1": "Mr"
        },
        {
            "$id": "3",
            "id": 2,
            "title1": "Ms"
        },
        {
            "$id": "4",
            "id": 3,
            "title1": "Dr"
        },
        {
            "$id": "5",
            "id": 4,
            "title1": "Mrs"
        },
        {
            "$id": "6",
            "id": 5,
            "title1": "N/A"
        },
        {
            "$id": "7",
            "id": 6,
            "title1": "Other"
        }
    ],
    "OperationStatus": true,
    "OperationMessage": "Records Available",
    "RowsEffected": 0
}
```

these are stored into array with create new class...?  is it possible..?

Comment: u want to extract the dictionary or something else

Comment: i want to create new class is it possible for that

Comment: for storing jsonobject * obj = jsonobject objectatindex(i)

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. Fix it and I can show how to easily create an object from it.

Answer (score -1):

I think your JSON is supposed to be this...

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "EntitySet": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "id": 1,
            "title1": "Mr"
        },
        {
            "$id": "3",
            "id": 2,
            "title1": "Ms"
        },
        {
            "$id": "4",
            "id": 3,
            "title1": "Dr"
        },
        {
            "$id": "5",
            "id": 4,
            "title1": "Mrs"
        },
        {
            "$id": "6",
            "id": 5,
            "title1": "N/A"
        },
        {
            "$id": "7",
            "id": 6,
            "title1": "Other"
        }
    ],
    "OperationStatus": true,
    "OperationMessage": "Records Available",
    "RowsEffected": 0
}
```

At the top level this is a dictionary with a key "EntitySet" pointing to an array.

To get this into an object...

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theJSONData options:0 error:nil];
```

This `jsonDictionary` will then have 1 key/value pair where the key is "EntitySet" and the value is an array of dictionaries.

**EDIT**

After updating the JSON the only thing that changes is that the dictionary will have more than 1 key/value pair.

Everything else is the same though.

**EDIT 2**

You can then save this into a new class that will look something like this...

```
@interface MyModelClass : NSObject

@property NSString *id;
@property NSArray *entities;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL operationStatus;
@property NSString *operationMessage;
@property NSNumber *rowsEffected;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

@end
```

Then the implementation would look something like...

```
#import "MyModelClass.h"

@implementation MyModelClass

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.id = dictionary[@"$id"];
        self.entities = dictionary[@"EntitySet"];
        // and so on...
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then when you create your `jsonDictionary` above you can get the class like...

```
MyModelClass *myObject = [[MyModelClass alloc] initWithDictionary:jsonDictionary];
```

Comment: -1 she/he is asking for class not dictionary. Read question first.

Comment: Well, this is now an object that has a property which is an array...  `myObject.entities[1];` will return the entity at index 1.

Comment: ? I don't know. I give up. This is just a standard object using a standard NSArray. Hope you get it working.

Comment: you need to implement entities class as well

Comment: @Chenna223 What does that mean?

Comment: @Chenna223 I think you need to start again on the question. It's not very clear what you are asking at all. I have given you exact details of how to take the JSON data and convert it into objects that you can use in iOS (Objective-C). You can now get to any part of this data with a single line of code. I'm really not sure what the remaining problems are. It sounds like you're very new with iOS. Maybe it would be best to start with a tutorial about using custom objects?

Comment: @Chenna223 But this is not server side code. My initial answer (converting the JSON into a NSDictionary) is all you need. Once you have that then everything you are dealing with is stuff on the iPhone. None of it is server side. You just need to manipulate the objects.

Comment: i want jsonObject [entitySet] and jsonArray forusing like this

jsonArray * ja = jsonObject getjsonArray[entitySet]

for(int i=0; i<js; i++)
{jsonObject obj = ja getjsonObject[i]

how to get this

Comment: There is no such thing as `jsonArray` it is an `NSArray` just like in my initial answer. `jsonDictionary` is a `NSDictionary` object. The array is `jsonDictionary[@"EntitySet"];` this is an `NSArray`.

Comment: i asking you i am working on customer registration.. i parse the url with {TITLE, FN, LN, GENDER, EMAIL, PASSWORD, PHNO} At that time Parse Another url with {title_name Id} how to parse that url...?

Comment: @Chenna223 I know, you keep asking. I have told you how to go from JSON to an actual object that you can use. It is up to you to do the rest.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate Api from your parsed NSDictory json data.

```
//JsonModel.h Start
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class ModelEntitySet;

@interface Api : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString * id;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray * EntitySet;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString * OperationStatus;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString * OperationMessage;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSNumber * RowsEffected;

+ (id) objectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;

@end


@interface ModelEntitySet : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString * Sid;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSNumber * Id;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString * Title1;

+ (id) objectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;

@end

//JsonModel.h End


// JsonModel.m Start

#import "JsonModel.h"



@implementation Api

@synthesize id;
@synthesize EntitySet;
@synthesize OperationStatus;
@synthesize OperationMessage;
@synthesize RowsEffected;


+ (id) objectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    id obj = [[Api alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
    return obj;
}

- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    self=[super init];
    if(self)
    {
        id = [dictionary objectForKey:@"$id"];

        NSArray* temp =  [dictionary objectForKey:@"EntitySet"];
        EntitySet =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *d in temp) {
            [EntitySet addObject:[ModelEntitySet objectWithDictionary:d]];
        }
        OperationStatus = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OperationStatus"];
        OperationMessage = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OperationMessage"];
        RowsEffected = [dictionary objectForKey:@"RowsEffected"];
    }
    return self;
}


@end


@implementation ModelEntitySet

@synthesize Sid;
@synthesize Id;
@synthesize Title1;


+ (id) objectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    id obj = [[[ModelEntitySet alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary] autorelease];
    return obj;
}

- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    self=[super init];
    if(self)
    {
        Sid = [dictionary objectForKey:@"$id"];
        Id = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Id"];
        Title1 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title1"];
    }
    return self;
}


@end

//JsonModel.m End
```

Comment: -1 if you're going to recommend a class definition and interface to someone then at least get the naming conventions right. Also, using ARC this won't work (with all the retains). And you're using iVars with properties which is very old practise. And `operationStatus` is an `NSNumber` not an `NSString`.

Comment: Really? You removed the properties? You should really be just using the properties and not the iVars. You get better control over ARC memory management using properties.

Comment: how to add json object...?

Comment: OK, variable names need to start with a lowercase letter and properties don't need to be synthesised (since Xcode 4) and `retain` should be `strong`. However, I think we all need to start again with this. We have both tried to answer and still we don't know what is actually being asked.

Comment: i asking you i am working on customer registration..
i parse the url with {TITLE, FN, LN, GENDER, EMAIL, PASSWORD, PHNO}
At that time Parse Another url with {title_name Id}
how to parse that url...?